# Metamask Vs Parity. Which browser extension is good to access DAPP using browser?

Tags: parity, dapp-development, metamask, dapp-design

I am trying to develop a DAPP and requirement is end user should be able to use DAPP from browser. I have two options available Metamask and Parity. Are there any other better options available to access DAPP from web browser? What are advantages and disadvantages of Metamask and Parity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the Parity chrome extension in your browser you need to run a local node.

> You are not connected to a local Parity Node. Seamless integration
>   with the Ethereum network is thus not available.

Metamask is more flexible and allows you to connect to the main network or testing network without running a local node. With metamask you can still connect it to a local node if you wish.

Metamask is better in case you want your user to use your DApp without running a node, for a developer using parity and running a local node would be better to use the parity extension instead (in case it provides more functionalities).